# Narrowing union select option type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a difficulty to make my custom select component figure out what type of option it deals with as it accepts both `OptionValueTypes[]` and `SelectOption[]` so, basically `number | string` or an object.

```
type OptionValueTypes = number | string;
type ValueTypes = OptionValueTypes | OptionValueTypes[];

interface SelectOption<T extends ValueTypes> {
  label?: string;
  value: T;
}

type SelectOptionType<T extends ValueTypes> =
  | T
  | SelectOption<T>;
```

I have written a type guard to find out which one the component deals with

```
function isInstanceOfSelectOption<O extends ValueTypes>(
  option: SelectOptionType<O>
): option is SelectOption<O> {
  return !!(option as SelectOption<O>).value;
}
```

I am trying to establish the type for an entire component so that I don't have to do `isInstanceOfSelectOption(option)` everywhere I need to use either `option` or `option.value`.

Whenever I hover over `options` TS thinks it is `SelectOptionType<O>[]` which can still be either `string | number` or an option object. If I use the option.value without calling `isInstanceOfSelectOption` everywhere I use an option object value I get the following TS warnings:

- `Property "label" does not exist on type "OptionValueTypes | SelectOption<O>"`
- `Property "label" does not exist on type "string"`

```
interface SelectProps<
  O extends OptionValueTypes,
  V extends O | O[]
> {
  value: V | null;
  options: SelectOptionType<O>[];
}

export const Select = <O extends OptionValueTypes, V extends O | O[]>(
  props: SelectProps<O, V>
) => {
  const {
    value,
    options,
  } = props;

  const [isListOpen, setIsListOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setIsListOpen(prevState => !prevState)}>
        {value}
      </button>

      {isListOpen && <ul>
        {options.map((option, index) => {
          // Need to do this every time...
          const isOptionSelected = isInstanceOfSelectOption(option)
            ? value === option.value
            : value === option;

          return (
            <li aria-selected={isOptionSelected}>
              // Can't just use {option.label || option} because of the above warnings
              {isInstanceOfSelectOption(option) ? option.label : option}</li>
            );
        }
      </ul>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: If your array can have mixed types you need to keep checking each item in inside `map`, you can do it only once if you place all the code related to object inside `if` and all related to `number|string` to `else` (so you'll have two returns but without ternary in them). If the array is always of the same type I'd re-write the type to reflect it and placed the check outside of `map`

Comment: The object/primitive type can also happen outside of the options map so I would have to basically copy and paste the entire code just for the few occurrences in the code. There must be a better way.

Comment: You haven't said if the array is mixed or one type only. In the latter case you can try to copy it to a helper variable of a narrower type. Or just have 2 components.

Comment: The components would be identical apart from one being for objects and one for primitive types. Sounds like I'll need to maintain 2 almost identical components.

Comment: As an option, you can transform number|string options to objects before passing them to the component so it can treat them in the unified manner.